# Email sending with nodemailer and mailgen error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, smtp, gmail, nodemailer

I am working on a project and trying to send email when someone registers to my software.
But I am not able to recieve email with nodemailer and mailgen library in react js.

This is my register controller or callback function :

```
const registerController = async (req, res) => {
try {
    const existingUser = await userModel.findOne({ email: req.body.email })
    if (existingUser) {
        return res.status(200).send({
            message: 'User already exists', success: false
        })
    }
    const password = req.body.password
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10)
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt)
    req.body.password = hashedPassword
    const newUser = new userModel(req.body)
    //email
    let config = {
        service: 'gmail',
        auth: {
            user: '*********@gmail.com',
            pass: '*******',
        }
    }

    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(config)

    let mailGenerator = new Mailgen({
        theme: 'default',
        product: {
            name: 'Mailgen',
            link: 'https://mailgen.js/'
        }
    })

    let response = {
        body: {
            name: 'BabysitEase',
            intro: 'You are registered successfully with BabysitEase',
            outro: 'Looking forward to see you at BabysitEase'
        }
    }

    let mail = mailGenerator.generate(response)

    let message = {
        from: 'fromsomeone@gmail.com',
        to: 'tosomeone@gmail.com',
        subject: 'Registered successully!',
        html: mail
    }

    transporter.sendMail(message, (error, info) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error)
        } else {
            console.log(info)
        }
    })

    await newUser.save()
    res.status(201).send({
        message: 'Registered sccessfully', success: true
    })
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    res.status(500).send({
        success: false,
        message: `Register controller: ${error.message}`
    })
}
```

}

I am not getting any error in console, and also I am not able to receive email.

Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you generate an app password from your Google Account to use Nodemailer?

Comment: @AudunHilden No, I am not able to see the app passwords option in my account, I have enabled the 2 step verification also. But still I can't see app password option.

Comment: i have generated the app password but didnt get mail. in local all mail are perfelty received but when i upload code to cloud server (linode shared vps) then not able to set mail to anyone. Can anyone help me